# How to specify an attribute "nullable" when creating a table, in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

As title says, should I just add a nullable keyword as a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle the default is that columns are nullable - if you want a column to not be nullable you have to add NOT NULL.

Comment: Alternatively, one can specify a column as nullable using the NULL keyword.  It's a matter of taste.